# Oracle: Duration of a scheduler Job

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, dbms-scheduler

I want to know the duration of a scheduler Job, but what I get from the DB is null !

```
select LAST_RUN_DURATION from USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS
```

Comment: If you have enabled job logging: `select run_duration from user_scheduler_job_run_details`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , please convert to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the 2 views:

```
SELECT l.LOG_ID,l.LOG_DATE,l.JOB_NAME,l.STATUS,dets.RUN_DURATION
FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG l
JOIN all_scheduler_job_run_details dets  ON l.LOG_ID = dets.LOG_ID
```